# How to draw a rectangle in a cell throught relative position of it within the cell that contains it?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the property `RelativePosition` in class `MapItem` is the relative position of the working point within the cell that contains it. The two components of the vector are always in the range *[0,1]*.  In our example image below the corrdinates would be something like *(0.25, 0.05)*.
 Each item has a property *RelativePosition* which is a Vector that defines the working point position relative to the item. For example *(0,0)* is the top-left corner and *(1,1)* is the bottom-right.

[image]

How to draw a rectangle in a cell throught relative position ? Thanks for help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about positioning the image by using containers? Maybe UniformGrid could fit for you. If you want the middle of the image at 0.25 from the left center it in the left cell of an UniformGrid with two columns.